# C# storyboard draw grid from bottom to top

Tags: c#, grid, storyboard, height, draw

I have a grid (which also could be a rectangle) which I want to draw from it's bottom to the top. It's a long lineair bar.

```
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="AliceBlue" x:Name="SkillBar11">
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,40" FontSize="16">IV</TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
```

and I can make it draw from the middle to top and bottom with this code in C#:

```
        Storyboard s = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation doubleAni = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAni.To = SkillBar11.ActualHeight;
        doubleAni.From = 0;
        doubleAni.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAni, SkillBar11);
        doubleAni.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
        s.Children.Add(doubleAni);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAni, "Height");
        s.Begin();
```

But I can't get it to be drawn from the bottom to the top, instead of the middle to bottom and top. Can someone help me out? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the anwser. You can orientate how the bar grows by setting a Horizontal or Verticalalignment in the grid properties. This way it will start at the position where you aligned it!